# Crystal Reports Multiple Columns and Rows

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to put multiple columns and rows in the details section of my crystal report.  I essentially want it to have 3 rows of data per line on the report, and span as many pages as needed to fill that space up.

Right now I am only getting one item per page, and some weird artifact on the next page, resulting in 500 rows of data going across 1000 pages.  Weird!

I am using 2 views to feed the report, one for header/footer and then the details.  The views are linked by date.  The database is refreshed daily and only contains the current days data.

I used to use Crystal ages ago but haven't looked at in 5 or 6 years.  I know this may be a bit of noob question to some of the more advanced users, but I need help all the same.

SAP Crystal Reports (from about dialog Version 14.0.2)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please post some pictures of the problem; it's hard to visualize.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by wanting "3 rows of data per line on the report"? Do you want the report broken into 3 columns vertically, with a different row's data appearing in each column? What data do you want to display? What grouping are you currently doing? Can you include the fields you want to see in the report within your question?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the paging issue - open the section expert and look in each section for page break set before or after. (It sounds as though a page break may be set on the detail section.)

Comment: Thanks Craig.  My query for the details section returns lets say 500 rows.  each row has 3 columns.  I would like to put 3 rows returned from the query into 1 line on the report.  To visualize it, lets just call the columns Destination Weight Size.  I would like to Destination Weight Size across the top of the details section 3 times, and have the report show 3 rows of data from the query on one line of the details section of the report.

Comment: Thanks Mark I'm not seeing the page break option in the selection expert is it known by another name?  My apologies for not being more fluent in crystal, but that is why i'm asking for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Groups in your report?  If so, do you have the 'Keep Group Together' option checked.  You can check this in the Report > Group Expert > Options... button > Options tab.  If you have that checked, try unchecking that and see if it helps.  HTH.

-NifflerX